# Facebook - App share link not working as expected

Tags: php, facebook, share

I have been referring to this page:

http://fbmhell.com/2011/09/bypassing-default-share-format-in-facebook-fan-page-tabs/

Although I cannot get any of the open graph meta tags to populate the share box.

```
<meta property="og:type" content="blog" />
<meta property="og:title" content="Snipe.Net on Facebook">
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.facebook.com/snipe.net?sk=app_215976961798590">
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.facebook.com/pages/Testbusiness/257200034311838?sk=app_168702143215541">

<meta property="og:site_name" content="AT&T Uverse Online"/>
<meta property="og:description" content="Test asdfasdfasfsafsfsadfsafsaf asdfasdf s">
```

Any ideas?

My new app will contain custom html with a share button. That share button needs to be per-populated with the info above.

Thoughts or ideas?  Thanks to any who can help me out.

Answer (score 0):

Declaring the opengraph structre urls in your  tag might help. This has caused me problems in the past. Your  tag needs to look similar to the below.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:og="http://ogp.me/ns#"
      xmlns:fb="https://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip.  It didn't work though. I think my main issue is actually my app url...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7655573/facebook-app-url-seems-odd