# Facebook - App url seems odd

Tags: facebook, url

Okay, Ive been trying to accomplish a very simple task.

How can get my new custom app url from:

http://www.facebook.com/pages/Testbusiness/898989898989898?sk=app_898989898989898

to:

http://www.facebook.com/jgarridodk?sk=app_898989898989898

I realize that i have the app assigned to a separate page (i created earlier) but Ive seen on other profiles that the first page you visit contains all the apps on the left side bar.  Im just not understanding why facebook has made this so difficult.

EDIT:
My objective is to have a share button in an app. I have been referring to this page:
http://fbmhell.com/2011/09/bypassing-default-share-format-in-facebook-fan-page-tabs/

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can't add tab to user's profile, so creating http://www.facebook.com/jgarridodk?sk=app_898989898989898 is not possible, sorry. You can only add tab to fan page (like here: http://www.facebook.com/cocacola). This type of page doesn't have friends, it gathers likes and is mostly used to represent companies/celebrities/activities. If you want to add application to this kind of page, you have to go to http://www.facebook.com/apps/application.php?id=898989898989898 and click "Add to my page".

**EDIT**

You probably want this:

1. Go to http://www.facebook.com/pages/Testbusiness/257200034311838?sk=page_getting_started
2. Click "Edit page" on right top side of page.
3. Go to "Basic information".
4. Click "Create username for this page?".
5. Enter username.
6. Enjoy:)

Comment: LukLed, how is this accomplished then? http://www.facebook.com/cocacola?sk=app_124432457634795

Comment: Hey thanks for the quick response. I do not see step 4 anywhere after i click 'App information' or 'App settings'

Comment: Never mind, i found it! Uuhg...It says " Your page needs at least 25 fans to have a username". How can i ensure the share functionality works if i need this?

Comment: @arkjoseph: It just works:) What do you mean by "share functionality"?

Comment: Sorry, I edited my question. My final objective is to have a share button. My current problem with my share code is that the og: tags are not populating the share pop up.

Answer (score 0):

You must be an administrator of the page you wish to put your application on.

- Visit http://developers.facebook.com/apps
- Click your application
- Click Edit App (Top right)
- Click View App Profile Page (Left hand side)
- Click Add to My Page (Left hand side)
- In the lightbox which appears click Add to Page next to the one you wish to add it to.

Comment: Ben, I have done this already. I was expecting it to work but the path has the page id and page name.

Comment: Is this when you visit the page which contains the app, then click the app name from the left hand menu?

Comment: Yes, After i click my page 'testpage' i then click the app and it displays: http://www.facebook.com/pages/Testbusiness/257200034311838?sk=app_8989898987955